# React ES6 and passing props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a `MovieSearch` component:

```
render() {
  const greeting = 'Welcome to React'
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <SearchAPI />
      <SearchAPIResults message={greeting}/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Which passes a string prop to it's child `SearchAPIResults` component:

```
// works
function SearchAPIResults(props) {
  return (
    <h1>{props.message}</h1>
  );
}

// does not work
// class SearchAPIResults extends React.Component {
//   constructor(props) {
//     super(props)
//     this.state = {message: props.message}
//   }
// }
```

The top code segment works. If I try the bottom code I get a message in my `MovieSearch` component:

> Type '{ message: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.  Property 'message' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

I know there's a difference between Class and Function components and I think the `SearchAPIResults` component should be a Function component since it's only displaying some data. But I'm still wondering how I would pass props between 2 Class components.

Comment: Does your class component have a render method? if so what do you get when you log `this.props`?

Comment: The app won't compile due to the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using TypeScript. In that case you have to tell TS what the structure of your component props is. Otherwise it doesn't know what the type of the `message` prop is supposed to be. You can do so if you're using either functional or class components, but the syntax will be a little different:

```
type Props = {
  message: string;
};

const SearchAPIResults: React.FC<Props> = (props) {
  return (
    <h1>{props.message}</h1>
  );
}
```

or

```
type Props = {
  message: string;
};

class SearchAPIResults extends React.Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {message: props.message}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: as a side note, doing this:

```
this.state = {message: props.message}
```

is generally an anti-pattern in React and you should avoid it. Don't use props to set the state of your component - doing so creates conflict and confusion as to what the "source of truth is" for the data in your app. If the `message` prop changes, your child component won't properly update because the value stored in `state` has become stale. Just read the `message` prop directly and don't store it in state.

```
class SearchAPIResults extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.message}</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I tried to define the `message` prop in the constructor which in hindsight makes no sense. Thanks for taking the time to explain the different aspects.